# Solutions of $e^z = \alpha$ in $\left\{z\in\mathbb C~|~0 \leq Im(z)<2\pi\right\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the solution of the following equation:

$e^z = \alpha$

It only has one solution in $\left\{z\in\mathbb C~|~0 \leq Im(z)<2\pi\right\}$

I don't know how to begin.
How can you find that solution of a complex function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $\alpha$ in polar coordinates, you can directly get the solution.

There exists $\varphi\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $\frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|}=e^{\varphi i}$. We get $$
\alpha=|\alpha|e^{\varphi i}=e^{\ln(|\alpha|)}e^{\varphi i}=e^{\ln(|\alpha|)+\varphi i}.
$$
So you get $z=\ln(|\alpha|)+\varphi i$.

Comment: Why is $α/|α|=e^{φi}$?

Comment: $\frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|}$ is an element on the unit sphere. And each element of the unit sphere can be written in the form $e^{\varphi i}$ with an unique $\varphi\in[0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\alpha=a+ib\in\Bbb{C}$. Writing $z=x+iy$,

$$e^z=e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)=a+ib.$$

Then equating real and imaginary parts,
$e^x\cos y=a$ and $e^x\sin y=b$. Solve simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, clear. But what do you mean with solve simultaneously?

Comment: I mean divide the two equations to get $\tan y=b/a$. Use this to find $y$. Then substitute back into one of the equations to find $x$.

Comment: how can you solve it? there are lots of variables in it?

Comment: Well then $y=\tan^{-1}(b/a)$, which lies in $[0,2\pi)$, and with a bit of work, it follows that $\cos y=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, so $x=\frac{1}{2}\ln(a^2+b^2)$